# Copy only updated table data from one DB to another DB

Tags: sql, sql-server, copy

I have two database say like backenddb and livedb (~10 gb in size having more than 50 tables).
I am updating livedb with backenddb so as to update it with the new data using mysqldump and then expanding it.This process first deletes all the table row,tables and then reinsert backenddb sql-dump into livedb during expansion.

So is there any otherway by which i can insert only the updated data rows from backenddb to livedb without deleting the entire livedb data?

Comment: Any data are changed in livedb, too? If not, I think you should think about database replication => See here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-howto.html

Comment: I want to keep replication as last option because backenddb is heavily loaded with queries all the time.Thus i am looking for some options without coupling livedb to backenddb.

Comment: Well in that case: Set a trigger on each table you want to replicate and INSERT INTO <db1>.<tbl_src> SELECT * FROM <db2>.<tbl_target>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through some more research i have finalized this methodology:
Create a backenddb dump using :
**mysqldump --no-create-db --no-create-info -uroot -hxx.xx.xx.xxx Db_dump > dump_name**

This will create a dump with row data  excluding table deletion commands.
Then in the dump file replace **INSERT INTO** with **INSERT IGNORE Into**:
**replace 'INSERT INTO' 'INSERT IGNORE INTO' -- dump_name**

Then expand the dump normally to the livedb this will insert only the updated data ignoring already existing data.

Note:-Any text occurrence of INSERT INTO will be replaced by INSERT IGNORE Into in the sql dump by replace command.

Answer (score 0):

To what i understand your question i can answer that you can take **differential** backup of backenddb and put that into your livedb.